# Error setting up MySQL with Identity Server(wso2is-5.3.0)

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

```
[2017-05-22 11:12:53,011] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.internal.IdPManagementServiceComponent} -  Error while activating Identity Provider Management bundle org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.IdentityProviderManagementException: Error occurred while retrieving Identity Provider information for tenant : carbon.super and Identity Provider name : LOCAL
```

This error occurs only when we create the database tables using the scripts located at `<IS_HOME>/dbscripts/mysql.sql` using the following command as mentioned in the documentation.

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'wso2_carbon.WF_BPS_PROFILE' doesn't exist

Comment: Please add more information to the question. which command? which doc? what are the databases you created? did you change master-datasource.xml?

Comment: I found the solution, first of all, either you can set up two separate databases for the Authorization Manager and the User Store Manager or just using Wso2CarbonDB, you have to create the database for identification and add it to the master-datasource.xml file and then just change in repository/conf/identity/identity.xml the datasource for the one that you just created like            <Name>jdbc/WSO2ID_DB</Name>.